# js манипуляции с несуществующими id, которое будет добавляться по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, разработка-игр

Я хочу сделать игру мачикоро на пк, изначально это настольная игра. 
У меня есть два поля для игроков, у каждого две кнопки, бросить 1 кубик, бросить два кубика. Еще есть кнопка "ХОД" по нажатию на которую ход сменяется(кнопки первого игрока становятся недоступными, а кнопки второго игрока доступными)
Но вначале кнопка бросить два кубика должна быть недоступной. А по нажатию на другую кнопку у игрока, чей ход сейчас кнопка "бросить 2 кубика становится доступной навсегда.
Проблема в том, что у меня никак не получается сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку разблокировать кнопку "бросить 2 кубика"
Была идея сделать переключение ходов для 1 кубика и 2 кубика по id, а id  для кнопки 2 кубика не добавлять, а после нажатия на кнопку добавить id.

```js
var g1 = document.getElementById('g1').disabled = true;
var g2 = document.getElementById('g2').disabled = false;

// Кол-во денег
  var money1 = 3;
  var money2 = 3;
// Место для выведения кол-ва денег
  var moneygame1 = document.getElementById('money1');
  var moneygame2 = document.getElementById('money2');


  // Активация/деактивация кнопок при смене хода
  function hod(){

      if (g1 == true){
      document.getElementById('g2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('gg2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('g1').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('gg1').disabled = false;
        g1 = document.getElementById('g1').disabled = false;
      g2 = document.getElementById('g2').disabled = true;
      }
      else{
      document.getElementById('g2').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('gg2').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('g1').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('gg1').disabled = true;
          g1 = document.getElementById('g1').disabled = true;
      g2 = document.getElementById('g2').disabled = false;
         }
  }
```

```css
.imgbtn{
   width: 64px;
   height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!--Кубик второго игрока-->
 <button onclick="cube2x2()" id="gg2" disabled><span class="cube1">2кубик</span>
  <img class="imgbtn" src="https://наклейкибум.рф/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/5180_0-450x450.svg_.png" alt="">
</button> 
<button onclick="cube2x1()" id="g2" disabled><span class="cube1">1кубик</span>
  <img class="imgbtn" src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/1012/human02/w128h1281349049040gnometali.png" alt="">
</button>
<!--Кубик первого игрока-->
<button onclick="cube1x1()" id="g1" disabled><span class="cube1">1кубик</span>
  <img class="imgbtn" src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/1012/human02/w128h1281349049040gnometali.png" alt="">
</button>
<button onclick="cube1x2()" id="gg1" disabled><span class="cube1">2кубик</span>
  <img class="imgbtn" src="https://наклейкибум.рф/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/5180_0-450x450.svg_.png" alt="">
</button> 




<button onclick="hod()" id="btnhod"><span id="font">X <br> O <br> Д</span></button>
```

Comment: А игроков точно будет только 2 ? Не захочется добавить 3-4 ?) Решения могут отличаться...

Comment: Хммм.. про это я не подумал... Пусть пока будет 2 игрока)))

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё очень просто! При нажатии на кнопку для включения 2ого кубика увеличивается на 1 переменная x. В функции hod удаляем эти строки:

```
document.getElementById('gg2').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('gg1').disabled = false;
```

создаем условие

```
if(x == 1){
   document.getElementById('gg2').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('gg1').disabled = false;
}
```

И всё!